# Joining multiple tables in SQL - Best practise

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I have 3 tables.

**Table1 : ContractMain**

```
ContractNo      SDValue Value   CityId     AreaCode
C0001           840888  18482   CY00004    AR0001
C0002           133500  35000   CY00004    AR0001
C0003           NULL    4200    CY00004    AR0001
C0004           73440   7400    CY00004    AR0001
C0005           73440   7400    CY00005    AR0002
```

**Table2 : ContractDetails**

```
ContractNo  Code    TxPr Amt
C0001       1       25   2102220.50
C0001       2       25   2102220.50
C0001       3       25   2102220.50
C0002       1       25   333750.00
C0002       2       25   333750.00
C0003       1       25   333750.00
C0003       2       25   333750.00
```

**Table3 : City**

```
CityID  CName
CY00004 AMR
CY00005 EEE
CY00006 TRE
CY00008 WSE
```

**Table4 : Area**

```
AreaCode AName
AR0001   COK
AR0002   TCR
AR0003   EKM
AR0004   RTT
```

My expected result is

```
 ContractNo     SDValue  Value  CityId     AreaCode   Amt  CName  AName
```

Script I have written

```
select  A.*,B.Amt,C.CName,D.AName 
from ContractMain A  INNER JOIN ContractDetails B on  A.ContractNo=B.ContractNo 
Inner join City C on C.CityId=A.CityId
Inner join Area D on D.AreaCode=A.AreaCode
```

Here I get repeated values against a ContractNo because in Table B we have got different values for column Code

I need to get distinct values for ContractNo. Which is the best way to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your query. used left join to ContractDetails in case there's no contract details entered for a new created contract.

```
select   ContractNo
    ,SDValue
    ,[Value]
    ,CityId
    ,AreaCode
    ,B.Amt
    ,(Select top 1 CName from City C where C.CityId=A.CityId) as CName
    ,(Select top 1 AName from Area D where D.AreaCode=A.AreaCode) as AName
from ContractMain A  
left join
    (select ContractNo, sum(Amt) as Amt ContractDetails group by ContractNo) B on  A.ContractNo=B.ContractNo
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please comment which one is better when compared with answer from @Zeina

Comment: you dont need to add additional fields on group by if you add more columns. and of course this is more faster

Answer (score 1):

```
select  A.*,SUM(B.Amt) TotalAmt,C.CName,D.AName 
from ContractMain A  INNER JOIN ContractDetails B on  A.ContractNo=B.ContractNo 
Inner join City C on C.CityId=A.CityId
Inner join Area D on D.AreaCode=A.AreaCode
GORUP BY A.*, C.Name, D.AName
```

grouping will remove the repitition and will give you summation of your desired field

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Tabl2.Code` maintains the versions and always 1 is valid version (which you can change based on your requirements), in that case you may try following query, this would eliminate duplicate entries from `TableB` which may result wrong `Amt` when you do aggregation

```
select  A.*,B.Amt,C.CName,D.AName 
from ContractMain A  
INNER JOIN ContractDetails B on  A.ContractNo=B.ContractNo  and B.Code = 1
Inner join City C on C.CityId=A.CityId
Inner join Area D on D.AreaCode=A.AreaCode
```

In case `Tabl2.Code` is not logical, you may generate your own version number using `ROW_NUMBER()` in which case the query goes as follows:

*Note: You can change the columns in `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses to generate a valid version number that meets your requirements*

```
select  A.*, B.Amt, C.CName, D.AName 
from ContractMain A  
        INNER JOIN 
                (select *, row_number() over (partition by ContractNo order by Amt) as VersionNum 
                 From ContractDetails
                 ) as B on  A.ContractNo=B.ContractNo  and B.VersionNum = 1
        Inner join City C on C.CityId=A.CityId
        Inner join Area D on D.AreaCode=A.AreaCode
```